# Creating Web Service client, error on XML elements

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am writing a simple Java app to send messages to a web service, which is deployed on .NET and I have no control over that, I am able to create the message and send it to the service but I get a 500 response the problem being the way java is creating the final XML basically the server expects something like:

```
<a:SourceSystem>FTP</a:SourceSystem>
<a:AuditDateTime>2018-07-14T15:30:06.1180404-05:00</a:AuditDateTime>
<a:AuditAttributes> <a:AuditAttribute>
<a:Name>ReceiveLocationName</a:Name>
<a:Value>UserUpload</a:Value>
</a:AuditAttribute> <a:AuditAttribute>
<a:Name>SendPortName</a:Name>
<a:Value/>
</a:AuditAttribute> <a:AuditAttribute>
<a:Name>FileSize</a:Name>
<a:Value>   0</a:Value>
</a:AuditAttribute> </a:AuditAttributes>
```

and my code generates something like this:

```
<ns6:string>FTP</ns6:string>
<AuditDateTime>2018-07-16T21:38:35.626-05:00</AuditDateTime>
<ArrayOfAuditAttribute>
<AuditAttribute>
<ns6:string>FileSize</ns6:string>
<ns6:string>0</ns6:string>
</AuditAttribute>
<AuditAttribute>
<ns6:string>SendPortName</ns6:string>
<ns6:string></ns6:string>
</AuditAttribute>
<AuditAttribute>
</AuditAttribute>
</ArrayOfAuditAttribute>
```

As you see the first issue is that the XML element names get created as "ns6:string" instead of the actual name like "a:SourceSystem", also it adds the "Array" tags: ArrayOfAuditAttribute.

The app was created by automatically generating the dispatch code from the WSDL so for example to create the first parameter my code is the following:

```
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<String> sourceSystem = factory.createString("SourceSystem");
        sourceSystem.setValue("FTP");
```

then once all the values are set I package the new event:

```
        AuditEvent aEvent = new AuditEvent();
        aEvent.setSourceSystem(sourceSystem);
        aEvent.setAuditDateTime(auditDateTime);
        aEvent.setAuditAttributes(arrayAuditAttributesXML);
        aEvent.setSearchableIndexes(arraySearchableIndexXML);
        aEvent.setAuditTypeName(auditTypeName);
        JAXBElement<AuditEvent> aEventXML = factory.createAuditEvent(aEvent);
```

and submit it:

```
        Long xml = svc.writeAuditEvent(aEvent);
```

The way java has created the elements seems correct:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "SourceSystem", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RCO.Audit.Model.DataTransfer", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<String> sourceSystem;
```

so I am thinking I might be missing to set those names somewhere but it does appear to be the case.

I apologize if this seems all over the place but I tried to include as much information as possible, if you need more information please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace mapper to the marshaller

```
        m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
            @Override
           public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
               return "a";
           }
       });
```

In your Entities add namespace declaration to all the entities that you want to belong to the namespace. For instance for SourceSystem element:

```
@XmlElement(name = "SourceSystem", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RCO.Audit.Model.DataTransfer")
public String getSourceSystem() {}
```

Do this for all the entities.

Comment: Thanks for this, I found the solution was the xml namespace was not being referenced correctly

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" appears to be the Object Factory, what I ended up doing to solve it was to manually add the namespace and tag name via the JAXBElement constructor:

```
        String namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RCO.Audit.Model.DataTransfer";
        JAXBElement<String> sourceSystem = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(namespace ,"SourceSystem"), String.class, "FTP");
        JAXBElement<String> auditTypeName = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(namespace ,"AuditTypeName"), String.class, "FileDelivered");
```

this allowed the xml to be generated by referring to the correct namespace:

```
<ns2:WriteAuditEvent xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RCO.Audit.Service" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RCO.Audit.Model" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RCO.Audit.Model.DataTransfer">
<ns2:auditEvent>
<SourceSystem>
FTP</SourceSystem>
<AuditDateTime>
2018-07-17T10:51:55.767-05:00</AuditDateTime>
```